# Culture date format issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use jquery datepicker for date input, and I have `DateTime` parameter in my `ViewModel` in `controller` `action`.

It works good on my PC which has `English culture`,
but other developer from Norway has problem with it, `DateTime` parameter in his `ViewModel` is always `null`.

Any suggestions of what might be the problem?

**One more thing**,

the date is shown ok in
`((System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper)this.Request).Params`, but in `view model` it is  `null`.

Comment: Which English culture? (en-US uses MM/dd/yyyy, but en-AU uses dd/MM/yyyy). You need to post back the value in the same format as the server or post it in ISO format (yyyy-MM-dd)

Comment: We changed the datepicker to use mm.dd.yyyy format and it works now, until we find out if it is possible to change default parser at the backend to use dd.mm.yyyy instead of mm.dd.yyyy.

Comment: You just need to set the appropriate culture in the server

Comment: How to do that? Now when we changed to mm.dd.yyyy it doesnt work on my (English) machine.

Comment: You cant have it both ways unless you post the date back in ISO format (yyyy-MM-dd), or you pass back a value indicating the format and/or culture, in which case you could use a custom `ModelBinder` to parse the value to a `DateTime` based on the format.

Comment: Ok, I send it in ISO and it works on both machines. All I need now is to make bootstrap datepicker to display data in dd.mm.yyyy format and to send to server in ISO format (if that is possible).

Comment: Why not just change the server culture? I'm not familiar with Bootstrap datepicker and if it has some options for doing this, but you can always handle the forms .submit()` event and change the value to ISO format. Other workarounds I have seen are to include a hidden input before the datepicker (initially set to the dates ISO format) and update it when a date is selected (the `DefaultModelBinder` will set the value based on the hidden input and ignore subsequesnt controls with the same name)

Comment: Because site is used mostly by Norwegians, and they want their culture, I cannot change that, the problem is that when Norwegian culture is selected the expected format is mm.dd.yyyy. If I can change only server datetime, not the culture.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably is the different date format between client side (browser) and server. Because of that default .NET binder cannot resolved that. The problem can be resolved by:

1. Writing custom model binder
2. Specify date format when the date is sent from client to the server.

Comment: "The default .NET date format is yyyy-MM-dd" - no, the default depends on culture. (If you mean "the format used by `DateTime.Parse`")

Comment: Jon of course you're right it was very bad shorthand, Let me edit this and sorry for misleading.